# require_auth for custom role

Tags: authorization

Some of my action require a special role "admin". What is the best way to handle set some user as admin and some action require the users with admin role? 
(In solidity, I can have a setAdmin() function and modifier requireAdmin().)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`require_auth2()`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#require_auth2) function, which can check a custom permission

> Verifies that name exists in the set of provided auths on a action.
>   Throws if not found
>
> Parameters
>
> - `name` - name of the account to be verified
> - `permission` - permission level to be verified

The official docs have [an article](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/accounts-and-permissions) explaining permissions in EOSIO, and you can create and manage new permissions using `$ cleos set account permission`